# How to display the properties of the current selected component in a JPanel using the Netbeans Platform API

Tags: java, netbeans, properties

I am currently building a small visual designer using the Netbeans Platform. All my components that can be placed on the JPanel show correctly in the Palette Window. 
What I am struggling to do at the moment, is to let the property window show the properties of the component that was either just dragged and dropped or showing the currently selected component in the JPanel in the Properties window.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to associate the object you want displayed in the Lookup of the palette.  Presumably you have a Node associated with that Lookup object.  Within that Node you need to override the [createSheet](http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-nodes/org/openide/nodes/AbstractNode.html#createSheet%28%29) method

Comment: Do you need more information than this?  I can provide some source code.

Comment: I know this thread is a bit old, but it would be great if you could provide some sources!

Comment: I will try to come up with a reasonable example.